# Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : error code 1 from Lapack routine 'dgesdd'

Tags: mlr

I got Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : error code 1 from Lapack routine 'dgesdd' using mlr when training the learner. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Which learner? Have you tried reinstalling lapack? It sounds like this is an issue with your lapack and/or R installation.

Comment: when using classif.lda

Comment: Works for me. Try reinstalling lapack.